# How do you send a user's manager user id via claims

Tags: active-directory, adfs

I have set the manager of a user in AD and I want to send the user id, email address, given name  and surname of that manager as LDAP attribute claim (ADFS is already set up). May I ask how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

For attributes in AD that don't appear in the dropdown when you are setting up claims rules, be aware that the dropdown is editable.

Refer: [ADFS : Selecting claim that's not in the default drop down](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2011/09/adfs-selecting-claim-thats-not-in.html).

So just go through the normal procedure selecting the attributes that appear in the dropdown (e.g. email) and typing in the ones that don't (e.g. manager).

For the claim type, it's just a URI so you can use something like:

```
http://company/claims/manager
```